# PHP Mail Not Sending To Email

Tags: php, email, send

This is my php code to send an email however it is not sending anything to my email

PHP

```
<?php
    mail("nishil.shah17@gmail.com","PHP Mail Works!","Awesome","Hello");
?>
```

Comment: you have one to many arguments

Comment: Is your [php configration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mail.configuration.php) set properly? Do you see any error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax is wrong You forgot to put `@` correct syntax is

```
<?php 
   @mail("nishil.shah17@gmail.com","PHP Mail Works!","Awesome","Hello");
?>
```

and one more thing if you are using it on **localhost** than possible it won't work so you have to check it on **remote server**

Comment: @ suppresses errors which you shouldn't do an the the 4th parameter is for headers which the sting "hello" is not

Comment: can i leave out the header or is it necessary

Comment: I added the @mail and removed header  and it is still not working... I am on a remote server

Comment: @nshah: I am using the same thing and it works for me.can you post the `errors`? And have you check your **spam** in your mailbox.sometime your mail goes to directly in spam

Comment: oh wow it was in my spam, do you know how to not make it send to spam?

Comment: @nshah: see the last argument of this function is its `header`. i am not sure about this but try this

`$headers = 'From: "Put valid email address"'` and put this variable `$headers` instead of `Hello`.

refer this http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php